# How can I find words sound or spelled similar to a given word?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

How can I find words that sound or are spelled similar to a given word?

For example, given "enervate", I remember seeing words spelled or pronounced similarly, but I can't recall which ones. Then I found "renovate", but I am still searching for a closer one.

Comment: In a rhyming dictionary, that's where. Not to be confused with words that are pronounced differently but written the same way: row and row.

Comment: what are your favorite rhyming dictionaries?

Comment: I don't use them because if I want to rhyme a word, I already know it, usually.

Comment: This could actually be a good use case for a generative AI. You could craft a question like "I'm looking for a word that sounds similar to 'enervate', but has to do with building houses. Could you give me 10 guesses?"

Comment: @YonKuma good idea. Someone has to teach me how to climb over GFW

Answer (score 1):

[RhymeZone](https://www.rhymezone.com/) helps you by finding words that sound similar to others.

One that I thought of when I read your question was *innovate*.

Comment: Thanks. I searched among those with the same number of syllables, and innervate seems to be close.